# aws s3 ls Unknown options: --recursive

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am trying to list the contents of an Amazon S3 bucket using the following command ([documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/ls.html)):

```
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket --recursive
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Unknown options: --recursive
```

The following is the version information for my Ubuntu Linux EC2 instance:

```
$aws s3 ls --version
aws-cli/1.2.9 Python/3.4.3 Linux/3.13.0-85-generic
```

How can I enable the `--recursive` option on my aws-cli?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'aws s3 ls --recursive' was added in version [1.2.11](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.rst#1211) - you are using version 1.2.9 - an outdated version. Please upgrade to the latest version.

```
pip install -U awscli
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have installed aws-cli using command `apt-get install awscli` on ubuntu, it installs the older version of aws cli.

You can install the latest aws-cli using pip command, make sure pip is installed on your system. Install aws-cli using this command

```
pip install -U awscli
```

To install pip you can use follow commands

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo apt-get install python3-pip -> On python3
```